# How to overwrite a specific table partition in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have a table with partition by date and I'm trying to overwrite a particular partition but
when I try the below code it's overwriting the whole table

```
query.write.partitionBy("date").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("orc").insertInto(mytableName)
```

but I want to overwrite a specific partition by giving the partition column name and its value
like `partitionBy(date='20-01-2021')`;

Is there any way to overwrite a specific partition?

Comment: you should use merge statement and do partition pruning to do upserts or overwrite any partition dynamically..

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the full path to the partition you want to overwrite. In this case you don't need to do `query.write.partitionBy("date")` and you need to drop `date` column before you write :

```
query.drop("date")
  .write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .format("orc")
  .save("/data/mytableName/date=20-01-2021")
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response.
 But is there any way without giving the path of partition column.? I'm trying a case in which the date and table value will be varying and passing as a variable

Comment: @M_Still_Learning non, you can't. You have to rewrite all the table or write like above directly into a given partition. You can format the path using your variables.

Comment: I've tried to overwrite  into table path but Inserting zero records. Can you help y?

Comment: @M_Still_Learning what is the problem? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach and adapt to your specific situation:

Need to set up table in hive or spark.

The follow this approach which is dynamic:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = spark.range(9).map(x => (x, (x + 100) % 3)).toDF("c1", "c2")
df.repartition($"c2")
  .write
  .partitionBy("c2")
  .mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("tabX")
```

Update a partition - contrived, in this way after setup

```
val df2 = spark.range(1).map(x => (x, (x + 100) % 3)).toDF("c1", "c2")
df2.repartition($"c2")
   .write
   .mode("overwrite").insertInto("tabX")
```

Look at effects and adjust to your specifics.

```
// from 9 -> 7 entries, pls run
val df3 = spark.table("tabX")
df3.show(false)
```

Comment: Thankyou. But I'm trying to overwrite within a specific partition column value not partition column. I'm able to insert into a particular column not column value as mentioned above. Can you help on that